# Behaviour of null values in Convert.ToDouble is not correct, is it possible?

Tags: c#

It is curious, friday I was working in the project of my company and I found some "bad" code or curious code. I said, I don't believe that error in Microsoft Framework.

I found that:

```
double? euros = null;
double test = Convert.ToDouble(euros);
```

This result of test is 0.0 instead of exception error.

I was surprised because I expected some kind of exception.

Can somebody tell me why does it happen?

Comment: thanks I dont understand why I can mark my code as you in my stackoverflow version

Comment: Did you even bother looking at documentation? MSDN states: ***Return Value:** A double-precision floating-point number that is equivalent to value, or **zero if value is null**.* [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55(v=vs.110).aspx]

Comment: plas, plas, plas, I did and the intelligence said if I set  double value Convert.ToDouble parameter is double!!!!!

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a **nullable double** to **double** and expect it to be **null** ?

The solution here is:
**just don't convert it to double if you want it to stay as null !** 

Your test variable is not nullable, so why you expect it to be null?

ToDouble method is doing what it must !

Comment: I am not trying, just I found in code, as you I said was some rare code... not normal. For that I said curious

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Can somebody tell me why does it happen?

---

Because that's the documented behaviour:

Whether it's [`Convert.ToDouble(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Convert.ToDouble(Double)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tfb1115(v=vs.110).aspx), the documentation states quite clearly:

(Under return value)

> A double-precision floating-point number that is equivalent to value, or zero if value is **null**.

As always, if reality doesn't match expectations, the first thing you should do is check whether your expectations match the documented behaviour.

*It may have a genuine reason why it behaves that way.*

### Some people argue:

---

**I don't think there is a *good* reason for it to behave that way**

That may be valid opinions, but if the framework designers genuinely thought that returning zero was a non-ideal result, they should have done whatever they thought best.

Obviously once the behavior was defined in .NET, it couldn't be changed for later versions - but that's not the same as saying it had to behave the same way as VB6.

Comment: for me the ideal should be an exception because they dont find the right result, I will accept your answer. And  I think in this case should be throw some kind of exception. That code I found that error for casuality because the behaviour in project was wrong, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 11):

It is all about how `Convert.ToDouble(object)` method's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#7d707859ba5fa685);

```
public static double ToDouble(object value)
{
     return value == null? 0: ((IConvertible)value).ToDouble(null);
}
```

As you can see, it returns `0` if `value` is `null`.

Also [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kx3x7f55(v=vs.110).aspx) as;

> Return Value
>
> A double-precision floating-point number that is
>   equivalent to value, **or zero if value is null**.

Comment: I know I can use code to control it but I was looking all the possibilites I have with the parameter i can set and the intelligence said me accept double value in one of the options. I think this accept null because ToDouble can accept strings and for this reason dont throw an exception but I dont know, I think it is an error of framework, I can not accept your code as right option.

Comment: @David This method returns `0` as `double` when you pass `null` as a parameter. I don't think this will change any future version of .NET Framework. I don't understand the connection between your _I think this accept null because ToDouble can accept strings_ sentences. And by the way, this is not my code.

Comment: I wasnt find a solution, just I will eliminate the conversion more simply for me. It is some situation when the project is bad programmed and a lot of people was in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to throw a exception when the value is `null`, you need to cast to `double` instead of using `Convert.ToDouble()`.

The following code **will** throw an exception, which seems to be what you want:

```
double? euros = null;
double test2 = (double)euros; // System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'
```